# Pyspark to concatenate/combine string columns with an escaped json column into a single json column

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to accomplish the following with PySpark.
Here is an input dataframe with 2 columns:

| string | escaped_json |
| --- | --- |
| Contact | {"id":"27","person":{"firstName":"Dan","lastName":"Jones"}} |

I need to transform the above dataframe into this dataframe. Note, the schema of the `escaped_json` column above varies (it is not fixed), elements of the `escaped_json` are escaped with `\` like `{\id\:\27\,\person\:{\firstName\:\Dan\,\lastName\:\Jones\}}`.

| string_with_regular_json |
| --- |
| {"string":"Contact","id":"27","person":{"firstName":"Dan","lastName":"Jones"}}" |

So far I figured how to transform just the "escaped_json" column into its own dataframe, but I need the string column (and possibly more columns) to be "concatenated" or included too:

```
json_column_df = spark.read.json(input_df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.escaped_json))
```

Please help :)

Comment: Have you tried exploding `escaped_json` column two individual columns `id` and `person` and then dropping `escaped_json`. Post that you can apply your current logic.

Comment: Use `substring` to remove the leading `{` from the JSON, form new key:value pieces using the additional column names and their values formatted as `"column":"value"`, then join everything using `concat_ws`. Finally, prepend a `{` to turn again it into a valid JSON.

Comment: @HristoIliev I will try your recommendation.

Comment: @teedak8s if you have a solution or a recommendation to accomplish the expected result as shown under "string_with_regular_json" above, please post it. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Since the json does not have a fixed schema, we can edit it with `regexp_replace`. Let's replace the leading `{` by what you want. Note that using `regexp_replace` with the content of a column only works within `expr`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.select(F.expr(
   "regexp_replace(escaped_json, '^\\\{', concat('{\"string\":\"', string, '\",'))"
).alias("string_with_regular_json")).show(truncate=False)
```

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|string_with_regular_json                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"string":"Contact","id":"27","person":{"firstName":"Dan","lastName":"Jones"}}|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```